# Postgres: Force scientific notation when serialization jsonb number

Tags: json, postgresql

So my issue is that I am storing JSON document in PostgreSQL and they sometime contains very small decimal number.

I have read online that when using JSONB, PostgreSQL, instead of stupidly saving the text representing a number, use internally the numeric type. Which is fine for me.

The issue is that I am losing the scientific notation used when I sent the data to PostgreSQL.
This wouldn't be too much an problem for me if PostgreSQL was smart when serializing the number and use the scientific notation when decimal notation lead to using too much zero.

```
test=# CREATE TABLE json (value JSONB);
CREATE TABLE
test=# INSERT INTO json VALUES ('1E-120');
INSERT 0 1
test=# INSERT INTO json VALUES ('"toto"');
INSERT 0 1
test=# select * from json;
                                                           value                                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
 "toto"

test=#
```

What I would like to have when running my select:

```
1E-120
"toto"
```

I think this is problematic because my code deserializing back the JSON as a limit for how many character to parse for a number. And I also think this is quiet inefficient.

(A solution would be to switch to JSON instead of JSONB but doing that I am losing all JSONB benefit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a CASE expression that applies different formatting rules depending on the JSON type:

```
select case jsonb_typeof(value)
          when 'number' then to_char((value #>> '{}')::numeric, '9.EEEE')
          else value #>> '{}'
       end as value
from json_table
```

The `value #>> '{}'` is a somewhat convoluted way to convert a JSON scalar to a `text` value (`value::text` doesn't work for JSONB scalars)

Comment: Thank you a lot for you solution.
If you have to make it "transparent" for an "ORM" (slick/scala) in the occurance reading the table, what would you suggest?
Something like a view I guess.

Comment: If your obfuscation layer can't deal with such an expression, then yes a view is the proper solution

Answer (score 0):

Use data formatting function and template from [Formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

`select to_char(value::numeric, '9.EEEE') from json; 1e-120`

**UPDATE**

Selecting more then one value from table:

```
select to_char(value::numeric, '9.EEEE') AS number_value, str_value from json; 1e-120
```

This assumes they are in different fields in the table. If not you will need to be more explicit about your setup.

Comment: How would you do if you have one string (json string) in the table and one number(json number). You want to read them all with one select but still want to format the number correctly?

Comment: If you can have different field for each json scalar, therefore you don't need to use the JSON type.
I updated my question.